# How to read in Data from Messy Excel Books

Tags: r, excel, csv, data-analysis

I've been dealing with patient and financial data from a hospital. The data is stored in .xlsx excel books. There are multiple pages within each sheet stretching horizontally and vertically. Some of the columns have neatly defined names as you would want for R but then others do not or have text in between and not to mention what appear to be randomly. At times 
a section has a title which is the result of multiple rows being formatted into one singular row. 
Unfortunately, I cannot show the data due to confidentiality.  Is there anyway around this when the data is far from being in a tidy format? 
So far I have been copying and pasting the data into a new CSV. 
While this was effective I felt that it was largely inefficient.Is this the best approach to take?

Help would be much appreciated

Thanks

EDIT

As I cannot show data this is the best I can show

Hi @Paul
So  Let me give a rough example

```
                 Jan   Feb  March   April
Income X    1      2      3           4
Income Y    2      4     4            6  
               Expenditure

                Jan    Feb    March    April                Another table here also
Expense   1        3         5           7
Expense   5       6          7           8

(Excel Bar chart)
```

Comment: It sounds like day-to-day life of a statistician/data scientist. Can you provide some 'dummy' data in your question that is an accurate example of what you have to deal with - and what your expected output is?

Comment: I've edited the question to show you a rough example of what I'm dealing with. 
I just want something in standard 'tidy' format with nice rows and columns for easy manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `readxl` package, the range option might be what you're looking for:

```
library(readxl)

df1 <- read_xlsx("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx", range = "A1:D3")
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#     Jan   Feb March April
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     5     7
# 2     5     6     7     8

df2 <- read_xlsx("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx", range = "B6:E8")
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#     Jan   Feb March April
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     5     7
# 2     5     6     7     8
```